# Unable to change value in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, sudo

I would like to change the value of a kernel variable in the kernel linux. I would like to change : /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier value (with the su rights).

However, I get the message :

```
bash: carrier: Permission denied
```

Do you know why I got this. I think this is quite common to forbid the user to change some values, but I am looking to mean to overpass this.

Thank you!

Comment: I found this in fact, this was no so hard to find : http://askubuntu.com/questions/341939/why-cant-i-create-a-directory-in-sys

Comment: If you are running something like `sudo echo 1 > /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier`, note that the opening of `/sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` is done by the shell with your normal user privileges before it runs the `sudo` command, and so is likely to fail with an `EPERM` error. You can run something like `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/class/net/eth0/carrier'` instead. That will run a shell as the super-user and do the redirection in that shell with super-user privileges.